# Why bootstrap multiselect does not load anything

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I have this simple form with a select option tag and I'm trying to style it with bootstrap multiselect. Unfortunately it seems like bootstrap multiselect is not loaded or something else... All what I get is the clasic html select multi box...

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/prettify.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/main.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>

<div>

<form id="tablefilterselect"  method="POST" action="http://localhost/admincrud/php/tablefilterview.php">
<br><br><br>
Select columns: <br><br>

<select class="multiselect" name = "coloaneselect" multiple="multiple" >
 <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input name="customtablesubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coloaneselect').multiselect({

            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            enableFiltering: true

        });
    });
</script>
```

Could please somebody help me? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you should load the `bootstrap` library *before* you load the `bootstrap-multiselect` script.

Comment: Why is your script code placed after the `body`?

Answer (score 5):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are including the `bootstrap-multiselect` script *before* `bootstrap` has loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you include `bootstrap` first...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

---

Additionally, you have a `<script></script>` block as a sibling of the `<body></body>` section.  A `<script>` block can only be placed as a descendant within the `<head>` or `<body>` section.

```
<html>

    <head>
        ....
    </head>

    <body>
        ....
        <script>
            ....
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this!!

```
<select class="multiselect" name = "coloaneselect[]" multiple="multiple" >
```